# Tika detect custom metadat fileds

Tags: java, apache-tika

I created a simple class that using tika library to extract metadata from files like PDF, html, XLS, DOC,..

files can have custom metadata. I need to detect that and ignore for first step!
But i can see how to do that with Tika!
this is my simple code to extract all metadata:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;


public class TikaParse {
   public static String resPFldMeta = new String();
   public static String resPFldMetaValue = new String();

   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   public  static String ParseFieldMetadata(String filename) throws Exception {

    int j;
     FileInputStream is = null;
     File f = new File(filename);
     is = new FileInputStream(f);

     ContentHandler contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
     Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
     metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, f.getName());

     AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
     parser.parse(is, contenthandler, metadata,new ParseContext());

     String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();
     // get field name of all  metadata 
     for(j=0;j<metadataNames.length-1; j++){
         resPFldMeta += "\""+(metadataNames[j]).trim()+"\",";
     }
     resPFldMeta += "\""+(metadataNames[j]).trim()+"\"";
     return  resPFldMeta;   
 }
 //.....
}
```

SO, My question is : how to check if the metadat detected is custom metadata or is normalized metadata??

Comment: i would like to explain more.. I need to escape a custom metadat fields because i have a pdf file that contain in here custom properties a  ModDate--Text field. It like ModDate standard property name!!

Comment: When i delete this custom property in advanced metdata and exceuted   my application with this pdf i have a correct result of metadata..

Comment: But when i execute my application without changing the metadata i have an error caused by parse methode